# Find other swords down the waterfall

Tags: pattern, computer-puzzle, algorithm, cellular-automata

This is another old pattern I generated with a 1D cellular automaton:

[image]

To me it looks like a sword hidden in a waterfall.

The neighborhood of a cell looks like this:

[image]

> What is the rule behind this pattern?
>
> Find at least one other sword down below and show what it looks like.

**Edit** The last part of the question doesn't really fit, so I accepted the first answer, stating the rule. I will post the pictures of other 'swords' mysefl to show what I meant. The title of the question can be interpreted figuratively now, only meaning 'find the rule to generate the pattern further'.

Btw, this is what I meant by 'other swords':

> [image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by find at least one more sword and show what it looks like.

Comment: @gtwebb, to find other swords one needs to actually generate this automaton

Comment: Do you have a generator you're using?  A quick online search and they seem to deal just with 1 generation.

Comment: @gtwebb, I use a Mathematica program I made. I think it would be more interesting to wait for someone to do it on their own

Comment: IMO the second requirement is more suitable for [programming puzzles and code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) but there is enough cross over that I'm sure someone will do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how the rules are written but it seems to be either

> 2nd generation alive with no first generation

or

> A number of 1st generation alive with no second generation (100,010,001,101,111)

Image

> Red is dead
>  [image]

Answer (score 6):

*This is based on gtwebb's answer, so please don't treat this as an answer in its own right.*

Quick and nasty Microsoft Excel VBA code to generate image:

> ```
> Sub RunIt()
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Dim r As Long
>     Dim c As Long
>     Dim cnt As Integer
>     Cells.Interior.Color = xlAutomatic
>     Cells(2, 8000).Interior.Color = vbRed
>     r = 3
>     Do While r < 500
>         For c = 8000 - r To 8000 + r
>             cnt = 0
>             If Cells(r - 2, c + 0).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 4
>             If Cells(r - 1, c - 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>                If Cells(r - 1, c + 0).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 2
>                If Cells(r - 1, c + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then cnt = cnt + 1
>                If cnt = 1 Or cnt = 2 Or cnt = 4 Then
>                   Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = vbRed
>             End If
>         Next
>         r = r + 1
>     Loop
>     Cells(1, 8000).Select
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> End Sub
> ```

First 500 iterations (generated while the VBA code was working sideways - the code above has been modified to work downward):

> [image: First 500 iterations]